# Codename One - Cross-platform BrowserComponent page loading indicator

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I'm developing an app with BrowserComponent. Sometimes the screen remains "all white" for (too much) seconds, because the page loading is slow: an app user can figure out that the app is blocked, but it's not so. I guess that a (well done) "page loading indicator" can be useful.

In the developer guide of Codename One, it's written so:

*On Android a native indicator might show up when the web page is loading. This can be disabled using the Display.getInstance().setProperty("WebLoadingHidden", "true"); call. You only need to invoke this once.*

Ok, but that indicator is only on Android and it's not nice. I need a better page loading indicator that:

- it's cross-platform (al least Android and iOS);
- it's not obtrusive;
- it gives the user an idea of the percentuage of the loading.

For example, look at this screenshot:
https://scdn.androidcommunity.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Screenshot_2011-12-23-18-55-56-303x540.png

In the screenshot, between the address bar and the page body, there is a thin, blue and good-looking progressbar, that is a page loading indicator.

How can I implement something of similar that works toghether the BrowserComponent?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a slider component to the north and fill it up as the page loads. The problem is we have no indication of the loading stage from the API. We only have the loaded callback to indicate that the loading was finished.

Comment: Ok, I've filed a feature request: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2188